# How can you make an Azure Logic App highly available across multiple regions?

Tags: azure, performance, load-balancing, azure-logic-apps, azure-front-door

How can you make an Azure Logic App highly available (HA), **specifically across multiple regions?**

Say we have two Logic Apps, one in North Europe, one in West Europe, just in case one region dies .... *I know unlikely, but ...*

So we have ...

- https://prod-18.northeurope.logic.azure.com ... etc.
- https://prod-12.westeurope.logic.azure.com ... etc.

I've looked at Traffic Manager, but it only offers ...

- Cloud Service
- App Service
- App Service slot
- Public IP   ... checked this in case it could be the IP of the Logic, but TM only shows App Service's in the subscription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to put Traffic Manager in front of the Logic App URLs as of today (the SSL certificates returned by the Logic Apps service would no longer match, and custom SSL certs are not supported yet).

As an alternative you can put API Management in front of your two Logic Apps. This would enable load balancing and failover between the two Logic Apps. Here are a few good links to learn about setting up Logic Apps + API Management:

- https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Microsoft-Integration/Protecting-Azure-Logic-Apps-using-Azure-API-Management
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/02/21/protecting-azure-logic-apps/

Note that Logic Apps have native / built-in support inside the Azure API Management UX.

Comment: Can you give more details on how you get API Management to do the load balancing / failover between two Logic Apps? ... I've read through the reference at ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-reference ... but can't find anything on load balance or failover ???

Comment: PS. API App's now in the UI, and Functions coming soon

Comment: To do a failover between multiple Logic Apps you will need to configure the API Management policy. More documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policies

Comment: @SzymonWylezol - which APIM policy exactly?

Comment: Would you need two API Management instances, one in each region, or just one?